# ERROR: return type mismatch in function declared to return my_fn

Tags: postgresql

When I return `table` from my fn everything is OK:

```
RETURNS table (o order_bt, c order_detail_bt, p price, ic item_cost)
```

But when I rewrite my fn to return type of same columns

```
CREATE TYPE my_fn AS (o order_bt, c order_detail_bt, p price, ic item_cost)

RETURNS SETOF my_fn
```

I get the error:

```
ERROR:  return type mismatch in function declared to return my_fn
DETAIL:  Final statement returns too many columns.
```

The function:

```
CREATE or replace FUNCTION "my_fn" ()
 RETURNS SETOF my_fn
 LANGUAGE sql
 STABLE
 AS $$
    SELECT o, od, sp, ic
    FROM order_bt o 
    LEFT JOIN order_detail_bt od ON od.order_id = o.id
    LEFT JOIN calc_point() sp ON sp.id = o.point_id
    LEFT JOIN table_fn() ic ON ic.fn_id = t.fn_id
    ...
$$
```

**What is the problem with `my_fn` type?**

**UPD**

If I rewrite:

```
SELECT (o, od, sp, ic)::my_fn
```

Then I get

```
ERROR:  cannot cast type record to my_fn
LINE 6:  SELECT (o, od, sp, ic)::my_fn
                           ^
DETAIL:  Input has too many columns.
```

Can not understand why exactly same columns work for `RETRUNS TABLE` =(

Comment: what are `order_bt`, `order_detail_bt` etc? and how does it match with the selected columns from the table?

Comment: @KaushikNayak: Have updated function at the question. They are table types